# Word/phrase to describe someone who talks exaggeratedly using colloquial language and repetitions

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word/phrase to describe someone who talks as in the example below:

> Ya, you should check it out. Check it out. And
>   you gotta try some Cincinnati
>   chili. It’s chili like you never
>   had. Trust me. L.A. Chili?
>   England Chili? Forget about it.
>   They make it here with cinnamon and
>   chocolate and they serve it over
>   pasta. Imagine that if you can.
>
> You oughta check it
>   out...*Check...it...out*. The zoo is
>   great. World class, they say.
>   Many, many important, you know
>   whatchamacallit, endangered
>   species, breeding programs, you
>   know. They’re famous for it.
>   Pandas. Other things. Owls.

Comment: Donald Trump? :-)

Comment: That cracked me up :P

Comment: Bombastic is close, but doesn't imply the slang aspect.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279242/word-for-someone-who-repeats-words

Answer (score 1):

A colloquial answer could be, you know what, check it out, some word in the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/motormouth)

> **motormouth**
>   NOUN
>   *informal*
>   A person who talks quickly and incessantly.